# Multiple column partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a very large table that needs to be partitioned by two columns. One column is an ID and partitioning is simple enough. The second partitioning should be done daily on the date column. I need to keep data of up to 30 days in this table and partitions older than 30 days need to be dropped. What is the best way to do the partitioning for this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need partitioning by the first column (ID)? If you think *"for performance reasons"* then just skip it. Mandatory reading - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#partitioning

Comment: You mean that you want a first partition on an ID column and a second partitioning on the data column? Only one is possible.

Comment: Partition is NOT index. Depends on requirement, sometime it is counter intuitive to remove the partition once you create it.  Partition is NOT a subset index of your data, it is the data. Please read this link to get better idea.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959930/mariadb-partitionning-last-3-month/38070779#38070779

Comment: please checkout the paritition usage directly here : 
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Partitioning is not by ID. It is actually by an account id number range. Different number ranges have different account types which is why i require partitioning on that column as well.

@Marco do you mean to say that it is not possible to have two partitioning schemes based on different columns on the same table?

Comment: I am not a partitioning specialist and never used it for MySQL but what I read in the documentation is that you can place partitions on different file systems to spread physical reads. To me this means that you can only use 1 partitioning schema. Perhaps you can try it on a development instance.

Comment: IIRC there may be partitions and subpartitions, but sure not two separate partitioning schemes. WHY do you *require* partitioning on types? The date part makes sense for quick drops of old data. But if you are concerned about performance of queries by *type*, use proper indexes instead.

Comment: I have not (yet) found any use of subpartitions that gives a performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

The use case of "purge after 30 days" is an excellent use of `PARTITIONing`.  (It is one of only 4 use cases that I know of.)

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, date)
...
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date))
(...)
```

Then every day do

```
ALTER TABLE .. DROP PARTITION ...
ALTER TABLE .. REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO
           PARTITION ...,  -- preparing for tomorrow
           PARTITION future ...;  -- this partition should stay empty.
```

[*Partition Details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/doc.php/partitionmaint) -- this is a follow-on to @jkavalik's "Mandatory reading", as @mootmoot provided.

Note:  No subpartition.  No partition by `id`.  No partition by account_id.  The big advantage is making the big nightly `DELETE` run instantly via `DROP PARTITION`.

You probably need some kind of index on `account_id`.  Consider a composite index.

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with or without partitioning) and the main queries.